# Rancher - New to Existing Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Is there any way to rehook the rancher dash into a cluster that already had rancher deployments on it? Working with Digital Ocean, I have temporarily lost access to a droplet. I'd like to use an existing VPS (or even deploy the rancher dash on the cluster itself?) w/ a cluster that already has rancher on it. If I take the yml it provides, will rancher detect its contents? Or is there more? I remember a token of sorts.

To be clear, my cluster is fine. I am specifically talking about the Rancher UI.

Comment: I don't quite understand everything you mentioned. Did you lose access to Rancher UI? Is your cluster node not reachable? What do you mean by "rancher dash"? What version of Rancher are you working with? What kind of yml? Please provide more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can re-import a hosted cluster into another Rancher install using the following steps.

- Take an etcd backup.
- Delete the cattle-system namespace using `kubectl delete namespace cattle-system`
- Remove all project labels and annotations using the following script.

```
for namespace in `kubectl get ns -o name |awk -F '/' '{print $2}'`
do
  kubectl annotate namespace $namespace field.cattle.io/projectId-
  kubectl label namespace $namespace field.cattle.io/projectId-
done
```

- Go to Rancher UI => Add cluster => Imported
- Run kubectl apply command
- Go to System Project => Namespace
- Move the system namespace like cattle-*, kube-*, etc. to the System project.
- Repeat this process for all application Projects.

Comment: Can you collaborate your answer? steps are quite complicated, how can I follow steps? like 'Go to System Project => Namespace' !